# Is It possible to sync Data Extension with Salesforce real time using Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I use lead capture to gather leads from Facebook and store them in the Marketing Cloud Data Extension. Now, I aim to synchronise this data with Salesforce in real-time. Currently, I employ Journey Builder to facilitate the synchronisation, and it is scheduled to run every hour. How can I ensure it synchronises in real time?